# Problem of having \begin...\end inside \ifdefined...\fi clause

Tags: beamer, conditionals

I am using `beamer`, and have a LaTeX code as below.

```
\ifdefined\VAR
\begin{itemize}
   \item blahblab
\end{itemize}
\fi
```

this does not compile, throwing an error:
    ! Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 61.

Line `61` is on `end{itemize}`. If I remove the itemize clause, as below. it works (of course)... Does anyone here have the same error before?

```
\ifdefined\VAR
   blahblab
\fi
```

UPDATE: If I put a separate frame inside the `\ifdefined`...`\fi` clause, then it does not complain anything. Maybe this tells something..

```
\ifdefined\VAR
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
   \item blahblab
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\fi
```

UPDATE2: A self-contained example code for reproducing the error...

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit} 
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \ifdefined\VAR
    \begin{itemize}
       \item blahblab
    \end{itemize}
    \fi
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have added a full example code... though it's mostly duplication of the one in OP.

Comment: Put `\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}` in braces -> `{\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}}`

Comment: @karlkoeller, this is working... if you make it an answer, I will accept it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It suffices putting `\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}` in braces and it will work.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \ifdefined\VAR
      {
       \begin{itemize}
         \item blahblab
       \end{itemize}
      }
    \fi
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Putting the environment in braces also works for the structure `\ifCustomBoolean ... \else ... \fi`, which triggered the same error, when an environment was enframed with `ifCustomBoolean` and `\fi`. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 5):

With `beamer`, `frame` is a peculiar environment which is processed in a nonstandard way. So the `\end` in `\end{itemize}` causes a bad pairing of conditionals (the error you get is `Incomplete \ifx`).

You can solve the issue by not making LaTeX “see” the conditional (or hiding `\end` in braces as suggested by karlkoeller).

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addifdefined}[1]{%
  \ifdefined#1
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \else
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \fi}
\makeatother

%\def\VAR{} % try also uncommenting this line

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\addifdefined\VAR{
  \begin{itemize}
  \item blahblab
  \end{itemize}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```